# Why adding a float to an integer using __add__ or __radd__ returns NotImplemented

Tags: python, methods, notimplementedexception

I previously asked the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59644166/adding-a-float-to-an-integer-using-a-method-not-an-operator?noredirect=1#comment105449612_59644166) of why `10 .__add__(5.5)` and `10. __radd__ (5.5)` return NotImplemented but the question was closed due to possible duplicates.

The answer of one of the "duplicates" state that:

> `a + b` does not directly translate to `a.__add__(b)`. It also tries `b.__radd__(a)` if `a.__add__` doesn't exist or returns `NotImplemented`.

That answer suggests that either `__add__` or `__radd__` should work, but neither `__add__` nor `__radd__` really work as demonstrated in my code above.

The answer of the other "duplicate" state that:

> a+b is equivalent to import operator; operator.add(a,b). It starts by calling `a.__add__(b)` and then, if necessary, `b.__radd__(a)`

Again, neither `__add__` nor `__radd__` do the job. So, those answers are basically paraphrasing the [Python docs on special methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__) which state that when a `+` operator occurs `__add__` is called first and then `__radd__` if `__add__` was not successful. What happens when `__radd__` is not successful either?

Comment: What are you talking about, `__radd__` is successful, it calls `__radd__` on the *argument* not on itself. So, you can think of `10 + 5.5` first calling `10 .__add__(5.5)` and getting `NotImplemented`, then it calls `5.5.__radd__(10)`

Comment: So *read this again* **carefully**: "`a+b` is equivalent to import operator; `operator.add(a,b)`. It starts by calling `a.__add__(b)` and then, if necessary, `b.__radd__(a)`" Note the order of `a` and `b`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I totally missed that when `__radd__` is called by "+", the operands are reversed. Yet, understand why '__add__' works on `float.__add__(int)` and not in `int.__add__(float)`. Why is `float` given more priority?

Answer (score 1):

I think you didn't realize that the operators are swapped for the reverse operation. It's `b.__radd__(a)` - it calls `__radd__` on the other operator!

So because `10 .__add__(5.5)` returns `NotImplemented` it calls `5.5 .__radd__(10)` (which returns `15.5`) not `10. __radd__ (5.5)`. If the `__radd__` on the swapped operators also returns `NotImplemented` the Python would raise an appropriate `TypeError`.

This snippet demonstrates how the methods are called for `+` (and what happens if both return `NotImplemented`):

```py
class T:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{type(self).__name__}({self._value})"

    def __add__(self, other):
        print(f'called {self!r}.__add__({other!r})')
        return NotImplemented

    def __radd__(self, other):
        print(f'called {self!r}.__radd__({other!r})')
        return NotImplemented

class U(T):
    ...

>>> T(1) + U(2)
called T(1).__add__(U(2))
called U(2).__radd__(T(1))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
---> 19 T(1) + U(2)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'T' and 'U'
```

Because `__radd__` is only called if the class of the operands differ I needed to create a second class in this example.

However you really shouldn't call special methods directly, if you need a function to perform such an operation you could use `operator.add` in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the nice trick to demonstrate how `__add__` and `__radd__` are called. I understand that if the class operands are not of the same type, `__radd__` gets called for help. 

However, I think I am still missing something - why does  `__add__` work in `1.5__add__(10)`and not in  `10 .__add__(1.5)`

Comment: In other words, why is the float given more priority? Why does a float allow itself to be added an integer and an integer doesn't allow a float to be added.

Comment: @multigoodverse That's just an implementation detail of Python. The `__add__` and `__radd__` of integers know about other integers. The `__add__` and `__radd__` of floats know about floats **and** integers. I think it's because integers represent a subset of float, while float represents a subset of complex, and so on. It's just important that one class knows how to deal with the other one to work properly. Why duplicate the int+float operations in float and int if (by the data model definition) it suffices that float knows about it.

Comment: @multigoodverse In case you're interested about the rationale for that see [PEP-3141](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3141/) and the [`numbers`](https://docs.python.org/library/numbers.html) module.